# How to achieve Left to Right animation in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to `Left to Right Arrow Animation` in my application like below Image:
[image]

I've tried below Code:

```
    ImageView arrowImage = sbView.findViewById(R.id.arrowID);
    ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation(0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 1, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f,
            ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f);
    scale.setDuration(700);
    scale.setRepeatCount(INFINITE);
    scale.setRepeatMode(REVERSE);
    scale.setFillAfter(true);
    scale.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
    arrowImage.startAnimation(scale);
```

But my code does't work as my expectation. I tried different solution from internet but failed to achieve result.

Answer (score 1):

this is translation, try TranslateAnimation

```
TranslateAnimation(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Animation XML file

```
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

   <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-10%p"
        android:toXDelta="10%p"
        android:duration="1200" />
</set>
```

To load this animation

```
viewObject.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.filename));
```

For handle movement position use xml attributes `fromXDelta` and `toXDelta` change Values

- **android:fromXDelta**

Float or percentage. Starting X offset. Expressed either: in pixels relative to the normal position (such as "5"), in percentage relative to the element width (such as "5%"), or in percentage relative to the parent width (such as "5%p").

- **android:toXDelta**

Float or percentage. Ending X offset. Expressed either: in pixels relative to the normal position (such as "5"), in percentage relative to the element width (such as "5%"), or in percentage relative to the parent width (such as "5%p").

For More Helpful Information visit [Animation-Resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource)